# Why does caps lock cause my Apple M1 to stutter?

Tags: macos

I am hoping to catch the eye of someone who has some insight into the mach kernel, as I can't imagine why what amounts to a key press interrupt would result in such system load.

Fairly heavily loaded M1 mac pro (think hundreds of chrome tabs). Activity monitor says it is 80% idle. I was playing a youtube video on chrome (probably not the native version), and noticed that hitting the caps lock key would cause the music to stutter. Opening up activity monitor and hitting the caps lock key repeatedly causes idle percent to drop to 40% and plenty of stuttering.

What gives? If I didn't see it myself, I would not believe it, as I don't recall ever having seen a working system behave like this.

Comment: -2, really?  Add a comment if you have a comment.

Comment: apparently this issue was fixed in 11.5.2, according to this https://discussions.apple.com/thread/253015514 source - maybe try updating and check if the issue persists

Comment: @brxken Thanks for the info! I really wasn't expecting that the issue would already be known and fixed.  I searched duckduckgo before posting here.  If you put that in an answer I would be happy to set it as the correct answer.

Comment: I would love to know what they did wrong to cause the whole OS to stutter on such a performant chip.

Comment: Sure, will do it now! It's a really odd issue but at least they addressed it I suppose, I don't even know what would cause such a thing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue was fixed in version 11.5.2, according to [this](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/253015514) discussion on Apple's website.

An update to the latest version of macOS should do the trick!

Comment: I usually hold off on updates for a few days to a week unless there is something really nasty.  I applied it this morning and this fixed it.

Comment: I'm glad to hear it's fixed!